light difference between scenes on player model
Here is a screenshot of same model on different scenes.

I'm trying to understand why the second one has that bright/light and remove it.
I want the model appear like the first picture.
Is this a problem with light? baking? rendering? model?
The only thing I figured is that disabling Post Process Volume reduced A BIT that light but it impacts all the scene.

This could be due to the lighting settings in each scene — particularly the skybox or indirect lighting settings. Can you show how you've currently configured those for each scene?

@DMGregory you owned! Just changed Environment Reflections from Skybox to Custom and it worked! Please poste it as answer

You have the settings that worked for you — want to screenshot them and post them as your own answer?

Solved by adjusting Environment Reflections settings, changing Skybox to Custom


You may want to show the custom settings you used too.
